# Can a button check password and filter?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Sorry to bother you all again...
I am trying to create a login page where upon inputting the correct UserName AND password, it would filter a subform below so that they can see only their comments. I have it so that there are two buttons where one checks the Username and Password via VBA code and another button filters using a Macro... But I would like for one button to do everything so that if the password is incorrect, then they cannot see anything. The filter button currently works without a password and as long as there is a correct username it will filter that without looking at the password.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub btnLogin_Click()
    Dim rs As Recordset

        Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tbl1Employees", dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)

    rs.FindFirst "UserName='" & Me.txtUserName & "'"

    If rs.NoMatch Then
        Me.lblWrongUser.Visible = True
        Me.txtUserName.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Me.lblWrongUser.Visible = False

    If rs!Password <> Nz(Me.txtPassword, "") Then
        Me.lblWrongPass.Visible = True
        Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Me.lblWrongPass.Visible = False


    Dim search_text As String
    search_text = Me.txtUserName

        If Nz(Me.txtUserName.Value, "") = "" Then
    Me.FilterOn = False
    Me.txtUserName.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If
Me.Filter = "UserName like '*" & Me.txtUserName.Value & "*' or userName like '*"
Me.FilterOn = True
Me.txtUserName.SetFocus
Me.txtUserName.Value = search_text
Me.txtUserName.SelStart = Len(Nz(Me.txtUserName. Value, "")) & 1

End Sub
```

Comment: Which is line 25? Why is code commented? Don't use .Text. In VBA you want .Value and since that is default for data controls, don't even need to reference it: `Me.txtUserName`. The `&` instead of `+` is preferred for string concatenation. Run filter code only if username and password are valid.

Comment: thank you for your response! I actually just made a macro that filtered the data and then added a Docmd to run the macro at the end of the code

Answer (score 0):

I decided to just make a macro and do a docmd to run the macro at the end of the code :) thank you all